# nested dictionary variable is not evaluated correctly with jinja2 template in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I have variables in the yaml file and jinja2 template as below.

#consul_common.yml

```
preprod:
 config_token: "SomeTestToken"
```

#config.env.j2

```
service_config_token={{ config_token }}
```

playbook is like below:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - include_vars: consul_common.yml
      
    - set_fact:
        config_token: "{{ (deploy_environment | lower) }}['config_token']"
    
    - debug:
        var: "{{ config_token }}"  
        

    - template: 
        src: config.env.j2
        dest:  /apps/account-service/config.env
```

When I run the playbook passing extra env variable `deploy_environment=PREPROD` , debug is giving the right variable value i.e. "SomeTestToken"
but when its templated out in jinja2 template, this is what I am getting in `/apps/account-service/config.env`

```
service_config_token=preprod['consul_config_token']
```

I was expecting the content to be : `service_config_token=SomeTestToken`

tried with this `"{{ (deploy_environment | lower)['config_token'] }}"`, did not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the variable `config_token` that is being set by `set_fact` contains the dictionary reference `"config_token": "preprod['consul_config_token']"`, and not the value.

Example (notice the missing Jinja delimiters `{{ .. }}`):

```yaml
  - debug:
      var: config_token
```

Also, in your vars file `consul_common.yml`, you are setting `preprod['config_token']`. Whereas in your `set_fact`, you trying to refer to `preprod['consul_config_token']`, which ideally *should not* give you the value of `SomeTestToken`.

So with corrections made to the above issues, the playbook like below should do the job:

```yaml
  tasks:
  # include vars with a variable name, so that we can access the sub-dict "preprod"
  - include_vars:
      file: consul_common.yml
      name: consul_vars

  # I have used the shorter "deploy_env" variable
  - set_fact:
      config_token: "{{ consul_vars[deploy_env|lower]['config_token'] }}"

  - template:
      src: config.env.j2
      dest:  /apps/account-service/config.env
```

Above playbook run with `-e "deploy_env=PREPROD"`, renders the template as:

```
service_config_token=SomeTestToken
```

Comment: preprod['consul_config_token']   was a typo from my end. I have edited it now.
so must I give a name to included vars to to make this work?

Comment: So when we `include_vars`, by default the vars are included to the top-level. You can refer directly as `preprod['config_token']`, but since `preprod` itself is the value of `deploy_env`. We can use an additional variable under which this sub-dict can be found.